# Java LocalDate / LocalDateTime - Hour Between

Tags: java, java-time, localdate, datetime-comparison

How do I know if an hour is between two schedules?

Example:

```
10:00 is between 8:00 and 12:00?
7:30 is between 8:00 and 12:00?
```

I'm trying this way:

```
LocalDateTime s = LocalDateTime.of (2017, 10, 20, 8, 00);
LocalDateTime f = LocalDateTime.of (2017, 10, 20, 12, 00);

LocalDate test = LocalDate.of (2017, 10, 20, 10, 00); (<- Must be LocalDate)

if ((test.isAfter (s)) && (test.isBefore (s))
   return true;
else
   return false;
```

It's returning the following error:

> The method isBefore (ChronoLocalDateTime ) In the type LocalDateTime is not applicable for the arguments
>       (LocalTime)

Comment: Your answer is here `The method isBefore (ChronoLocalDateTime <?>) In the type LocalDateTime is not applicable for the arguments
(LocalTime)`. Make it `LocalDateTime`

Comment: Where do you find a [`LocalDate.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#of-int-int-int-) with 5 parameters ? A `LocalDate` don't hold time information...

Comment: FYI `LocalDate` doesn't store the hours and minutes so your code won't compile.

Comment: For me, the method `LocalDate.of(5 arguments)` doesn't even compile. Not surprising since it only contains date and it contains no time information.

Comment: Not sure if it's a typo, but `(test.isAfter(s)) && (test.isBefore(s))` is checking if `test` is after `s` **and** `test` is before `s`. This will **never** be true.

Comment: In general, you shouldn't do stuff like `if (x) return true; else return false;` - just return `x` directly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why include dates if you are only interested in times?

```
LocalTime s = LocalTime.of (8, 0);
LocalTime f = LocalTime.of (12, 0);

LocalTime test = LocalTime.of (10, 0);

if (test.isAfter (s) && test.isBefore (f))
```

And if you received a `LocalDateTime`, you can call `ldt.toLocalTime()`.

Answer (score 0):

Then go to LocalDates; maybe with `!after` instead of `before`.

```
return test.isAfter(s.toLocalDate()) && test.isBefore(f.toLocalDate());
```

Answer (score 0):

You question is wrong since the code doesn't even compile, but I guess you are looking for the following methods on your `LocalDate` object:

- `atStartOfDay()` converts a `LocalDate` to `LocalDateTime` with the time at `00:00`
- `atTime(int hour, int minute)` converts a `LocalDate` to `LocalDateTime` with the time provided